# Display no result after merging 2 table and do a where statement in Laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-livewire

I trying to merge 2 table of the same database as follow

```
$this->make_model_list = DB::table('car__models')->select(
            "car__makes.id",
            "car__makes.name AS make_name",
            "car__models.id AS model_id",
            "car__models.name AS model_name",
            "car__models.car__make_id",
            DB::raw("CONCAT(`car__makes`.`name`,' ',`car__models`.`name`) AS make_model")
        )->leftJoin('car__makes', 'car__makes.id', '=', 'car__models.car__make_id')
        ->get();
```

And then I do a where statement as follow

```
$this->makemodels = $this->make_model_list->where('make_model', 'like', '%' . $this->makemodel . '%');
```

But it return [].

Your advices to this is greatly appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you're adding a `where()` after your `get()`

The `get()` executes your query and returns a collection of objects.

It's okay to call a `where()` on a collection but the parameters you've given your `where()` are more appropriate for a DB query.

I would suggest you drop the `get()` from your query. (For the sake of good variable naming you should then call `make_model_list` `make_model_list_query`)

```
$this->make_model_list_query = DB::table('car__models')->select(
        "car__makes.id",
        "car__makes.name AS make_name",
        "car__models.id AS model_id",
        "car__models.name AS model_name",
        "car__models.car__make_id",
        DB::raw("CONCAT(`car__makes`.`name`,' ',`car__models`.`name`) AS make_model")
    )->leftJoin('car__makes', 'car__makes.id', '=', 'car__models.car__make_id');
```

And then call the `get()` after you've added your `where()`

```
$this->make_model_list_query->where('make_model', 'like', '%' . $this->makemodel . '%')->get();
```

It would probably make everything much easier for you if you created eloquent models for you tables and relationships between the models so you can take advantage of the relationship and scopes that can make your filtering much cleaner.
Models handle a huge amount of the query writing for you.

EDIT:

Having not noticed that your where was on your concatenated value at first I missed that your query would throw a SQL error.
You can't run your where on the aliased output of your concat.
So you would need to put the concat in the where clause too. Like so:

```
$this->make_model_list_query->where(DB::raw("CONCAT(`car__makes`.`name`,' ',`car__models`.`name`)"), 'like', '%' . $this->makemodel . '%')->get();
```

Be sure to check out the links I added in the comments for Eloquent Models.

Comment: Hi Jon, thanks for the quick reply, I had done as you suggest and I had encountered another issue. which is as shown: 
SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'make_model' in 'where clause' (SQL: select `car__makes`.`id`, `car__makes`.`name` as `make_name`, `car__models`.`id` as `model_id`, `car__models`.`name` as `model_name`, `car__models`.`car__make_id`, CONCAT(`car__makes`.`name`,' ',`car__models`.`name`) AS make_model from `car__models` left join `car__makes` on `car__makes`.`id` = `car__models`.`car__make_id` where `make_model` like %c%)

Comment: And will also keen to know how to do the above using Models. Thanks

Comment: For information on models check you Laravel's docs on Eloquent ORM https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent There's a little bit of start up required but once you have the concepts it really opens up Laravel for you. Also check out Laracasts https://laracasts.com/series/laravel-6-from-scratch Some of their content is free, not sure if this one is or not.

Comment: I've added a solution to your SQL error. The concatenation needs to be specified in the where clause too.

Comment: It works. Thanks alot. FYI there is a missing ") after name'). Had include the  correct code for other to reference to: $this->make_model_list_query->where(DB::raw("CONCAT(`car__makes`.`name`,' ',`car__models`.`name`)"), 'like', '%' . $this->makemodel . '%')->get(); Will check out the link alot.

Comment: Ah yes, so I did. A sloppy copy+paste job there!

Comment: Is great that you able to help solve my issues. Thanks